# How to make a hub section scrollable when a textblock becomes to large to fit on the page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have made an app that implements a hub control and on the app there is a way to add information on the top.

Each time information is added it would be added to a textblock on the bottom part of the page. The problem is when the textblock gets filled up and goes off the page. The hub section isn't scrollable and the information cant be seen.

Is there a way to make a hub section scrollable as more information is added to a textblock? This is what my code looks like now for the add button event.

```
private void abtnAddHours_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string hoursData;
    hoursData = string.Format("{0}:{1}\n{2:d}\n\n", tbHours.Text, tbMinutes.Text, dtpkrHoursDate.Date);
    txtblkHoursData.Text += hoursData;
}
```

any help is appreciated thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your controls inside `<ScrollViewer />`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202907%28v=vs.105%29.aspx